Is it safe to place a dehumidifier near a gas furnace in a Laundry/Furnace room?
I recently purchased a new dehumidifier and I'm considering placing it in my laundry/furnace room since there's a drain available. However, I'm a bit concerned about any potential fire risks due to the proximity of the dehumidifier to the gas furnace. Has anyone had experience with this setup, or could anyone provide some advice on whether it's safe?


A dehumidifier is basically an air conditioner, chilling the air to condense out the moisture, then releasing it and the heat back into the room. (Which means that overall it will tend to keep the room as it reduces the moisture. Thank you, JC Maxwell.)
As such, it has pumps and fans and switches and relays, some of which may occasionally create sparks. So if you got a serious gas leak, it could be a source of ignition.
But if you got a serious gas leak, odds are that half the things in your basement could be sources of ignition, so I don't think it actually increases the hazard at all.

Yeah, I mean, unless you have serious short-circuiting of your returns and registers, the air there should be basically the same humidity as the rest of the home.
